# Encrypt large strings in C# - Best practices

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am working on a C# project, and I'd like to know what are the best/most efficient ways to encrypt large strings?

There is already an encryption mechanism in place to encrypt passwords and other smaller fields. I'm using RSA encryption there (the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class), but i'm currently able to encrypt rather smaller strings - upto ~150 characters with my 2048 bit key.

What would be the best way to encrypt larger strings - ~4000 characters? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty common to use a mixture of symmetric and asymmetric encryption a.k.a. [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) for encryption of large data.

Technically speaking you can either generate symmetric i.e. AES key on your own, encrypt large data with it and then encrypt small symmetric key with asymmetric i.e. RSA key; or you can use [EnvelopedCms class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your specific use case) that will do it for you and will put all required data into [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) data structure that should also be interoperable with many widely used cryptographic libraries and tools.